# How can I call R functions from an Excel vba script on both Mac and Windows?

Tags: r, excel, macos, vba, cross-platform

I'm writing a macro-enabled Excel workbook to automate some data processing for the people in my lab. I'd like to be able to call R functions from my vba scripts, but some of the users will be working on Macs. In my search, I've seen plenty of ways to call R functions from Excel on a Windows machine, but not much for Macs.

So far, I think my best shot is to get them all to install [F# R Type Provider](http://bluemountaincapital.github.io/FSharpRProvider/) and [F# Excel Provider](http://fsprojects.github.io/ExcelProvider/). Then, I'll have the Excel vba script execute an F# script to get the data I want from Excel, call my R function on it, and then return the result to excel. (Although, this might end up being way over my head)

Is there another, more straightforward way to get a single vba script to call R functions on Macs and PCs?

Comment: Please be aware that on Mac vba is not the same as on Windows for a lot of things (can be a real pain...)

Comment: This could very well be a misconception, but my impression is that all the differences between VBA on the two OSs exist as limitations on the Mac end. If this were the case, one could be led to presume that VBA that works on a Mac would also work on Windows given some differences in the way i/o is handled.  Am I up a tree on this?

Comment: I would say yes, but there are even some functions that exist on Mac but not on Windows but the other way around I know that it is way worse. I started VBA on windows and then went over to mac and all I'm having are problems...

Comment: I have a tip for you: there is a function to test wheather the operating system is Mac or windows. You could test this on the workbook_open sub and then either get to run the mac or the windows code. this way you wouldn't be neither restricted on Windows nor on Mac as they will use the "native functions" of the office version on either operating system.